# AmMap themes not working

Tags: javascript, svg, themes, ammap

I have successfuly created an AmMap. Now I wanted to apply a theme to it and proceeded exactly as instructed in this tutorial:

http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/working-with-themes/

However, for some reason, even though the theme CSS is loaded, it doesnt work. Any suggestions what might be wrong?

My code is:

```
<html>
<script src="/js/ammap/ammap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/ammap/themes/dark.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<script>


AmCharts.ready(function() {
    var map = new AmCharts.AmMap(AmCharts.themes.dark);
    map.pathToImages = "/js/ammap/images/";

    var dataProvider = {
        mapURL: "cz_okresy.svg",
        getAreasFromMap:true                    
    }; 

    map.dataProvider = dataProvider;

    map.areasSettings = {
        rollOverOutlineThickness:1,
        outlineThickness:1,
        rollOverOutlineAlpha:1,
        rollOverAlpha:0.8,
        alpha:0.5,
        outlineAlpha:1,
    };

    map.label = {
        text: "20",
    }

    map.write("mapdiv");
});
</script>
<div id="mapdiv" style="width: 90%; height: 90%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of the above is here:
http://meteopage.com/beta/czdistrictmap.html

Comment: I have also tried adding AmCharts.theme = AmCharts.themes.dark; before variable map is created and I got the exact same result.

Comment: theme does not change background color, maybe that's the problem? Or other elements are not changed too?

Comment: I'm noticing this problem as well in my code where the background color and bars don't change.